# iCloud + Preloaded CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I have database with some default content. How can I use iCloud to sync changes in database on different devices?
I know how sync devices if CoreData was empty first and I can migrate from external sqlite file to CoreData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an existing Core Data store and you want to add iCloud support, you'll need to transfer all of your existing data to a new data store and save the result. This is necessary because iCloud only generates transactions when you save changes-- so you need to effectively save changes for *everything* to jumpstart the syncing process.

In most cases you can do this in a single step by using `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`'s `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:`. Pass in the same iCloud options that you would use when calling `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:`. Use this alternate approach only when moving from a non-iCloud data store to one that does use iCloud.

Also, **beware** of using iCloud with Core Data. It has not earned a reputation for reliability. Pay close attention to Apple's documentation and sample projects, and even then be prepared for it to just not work sometimes.